# image to take the all space of the container

Tags: html, css

attached a js fiddle to show my issue. I want the orange image to take all the top area of the card and not have padding on the top and sides. the image should show from the very  top and takes all the sides with no space
[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eladnm/t6zcv5y4/6/)

```css
.pricing-card {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  max-height: 463px;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 70px #2e231d1a;
  border-radius: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  min-height: 550px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}

#rectangle {
  max-width: 330px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-container">
  <div v-if="checkDomainTrial" class="price-text">
    Get your entire first month free on us!
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <div id="wait">Wait! Don't go yet!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pricing-card">
    <div class="pricing-card-header">
      <img id="rectangle" src="https://i.ibb.co/FVkvCv5/Rectangle-cancellation.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: So remove the padding from the image itself

Comment: Your HTML code seem to be not valid, as there are some missing end tag.

Comment: You have no padding, your image has transparent spaces around the colored part

Comment: Your image contains transparent empty space, the image does take up the entire area.

Comment: thanks. I ended up removing the padding from the image itself. i want aware of that